# How do I retrieve data that meets a specific condition in an XML file?

Tags: c#

I have an XML file, and I want to retrieve the `brandname`  when `brandcode` is `001` from the following XML.

```
    <Root>
-   <data>
  <Companycode>TF</Companycode> 
  <Productcode>00001</Productcode> 
  <Productname>VPU</Productname> 
  <Brandcode>001</Brandcode> 
  <Brandname>DB</Brandname> 
  </data>
- <data>
  <Companycode>TF</Companycode> 
  <Productcode>00002</Productcode> 
  <Productname>SENDERCARD</Productname> 
  <Brandcode>002</Brandcode> 
  <Brandname>LINSN</Brandname> 
  </data>
</Root>
```

This is my code; I need to assign Brand Name here:

```
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(@"codedata.xml");
            textReader.Read();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(textReader);

            XmlNodeList BCode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Brandcode");
            XmlNodeList BName = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Brandname");
            for (int i = 0; i < BCode.Count; i++)
            {
                if (BCode[i].InnerText =="001")
                {
                    string brandname = BName[i].InnerText;
                }
                    //Console.WriteLine(BName[i].InnerText);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try In this way...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlReading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create an instance of the XmlTextReader and call Read method to read the file            
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\myxml.xml");
            textReader.Read();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(textReader);

            XmlNodeList BCode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Brandcode");
            XmlNodeList BName = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Brandname");
            for (int i = 0; i < BCode.Count; i++)
            {
                if (BCode[i].InnerText == "001")
                    Console.WriteLine(BName[i].InnerText);                
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i used string brandcode; how to assign here  if (BCode[i].InnerText == "001"), i want to check like this if (BCode[i].InnerText == brandcodevalue)

Comment: brandcode is 001, this value is getting from another method, so i assigned string brandcode = Convert.ToString(keyvalue).Substring(7);. Here the value is dynamic,it may change to 002, 003 or..., so i want to check the brandcode dynamically.

Comment: in the place of "001" in if condition, i want to check string brandcode.

Comment: Well In that case you directly check the condition with string... Suppose in the above example i appended 001 to string sample = "001" and i put the condition if (BCode[i].InnerText == sample) ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this `XPath`: `//Brandname[../Brandcode[text()='001']]`

Using [`XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode):

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
var Brandcode = "001";
var xpath = String.Format(@"//Brandname[../Brandcode[text()='{0}']]", 
                          Brandcode);
var Brandname = document.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

and using [`XDocument.XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelement.aspx):

```
var document = XDocument.Load("fileName");
var name = document.XPathSelectElement(xpath).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use Xml.Linq namespace, with XDocument class to load and select the exact element from the xml file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"filePath");
var query = doc.Descendants("Root").Where(w => w.Element("Brandcode").Value == "001").Select(s => new { s.Element("Brandname").Value }).FirstOrDefault();
string brandname = query.Value;
```

Comment: i tried your code, but i am getting the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Define the brandname as string and assign null to it and then use the brand name where ever you want....

```
namespace XmlReading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create an instance of the XmlTextReader and call Read method to read the file            
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\myxml.xml");
            textReader.Read();

            string brandname = null;

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(textReader);

            XmlNodeList BCode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Brandcode");
            XmlNodeList BName = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Brandname");
            for (int i = 0; i < BCode.Count; i++)
            {
                if (BCode[i].InnerText == "001")
                {
                    brandname = BName[i].InnerText;                    
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(brandname);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```